# Routing with 'if' statement

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I need my site to be behind a login wall. so far I have done this with an "if" statement:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('pages.feed');
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
});
```

i also need to call the feedController though. how can i add

> 'feedController@index'

to the statement?

Comment: Simple add middleware in route  for example   `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
 
 Route::get('feed','feedController@index');
 
});`

Comment: @JYoThI ; If OP think in all the way its good to put in auth middleware but , for now its not the answer as it will not work for guest users as he want to show `auth.login`

Comment: i did end-up going for a middleware solution, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your condition in controller not in web.php routing

```
Route::get('/', 'feedController@index');
```

and in `feedController` controller

```
function index(){
    .........
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('pages.feed');
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

Also be sure to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`
or just `\` as `if (\Auth::check()) {`